# Expand any gameObject in HoloLens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I am trying to create an explosion effect for gameObject for HoloLens 2 development. I want to create an effect like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dA11P4P0VO8&feature=emb_logo (Astronaut model from Microsoft) for my gameObject.

When I tried to use the below script, my object explodes but it goes back from its initial position.

Below is my script.

Explosion script:

```
public class ModelExplosion : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<SubMeshes> childMeshRenderers;
    bool isInExplodedView = false;
    public float explosionSpeed = 0.1f;
    bool isMoving = false;
    private void Awake () {
        childMeshRenderers = new List<SubMeshes> ();
        foreach (var item in GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer> ()) {
            SubMeshes mesh = new SubMeshes ();
            mesh.meshRenderer = item;
            mesh.originalPosition = item.transform.position;
            mesh.explodedPosition = item.bounds.center * 1.5f;
            childMeshRenderers.Add (mesh);
        }
    }
    private void Update () {
        if (isMoving) {
            if (isInExplodedView) {
                foreach (var item in childMeshRenderers) {
                    item.meshRenderer.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (item.meshRenderer.transform.position, item.explodedPosition, explosionSpeed);
                    if (Vector3.Distance (item.meshRenderer.transform.position, item.explodedPosition) < 0.001f) {
                        isMoving = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                foreach (var item in childMeshRenderers) {
                    item.meshRenderer.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (item.meshRenderer.transform.position, item.originalPosition, explosionSpeed);
                    if (Vector3.Distance (item.meshRenderer.transform.position, item.originalPosition) < 0.001f) {
                        isMoving = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void ToggleExplodedView () {
        if (isInExplodedView) {
            isInExplodedView = false;
            isMoving = true;
        } else {
            isInExplodedView = true;
            isMoving = true;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class SubMeshes {
        public MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
        public Vector3 originalPosition;
        public Vector3 explodedPosition;
    }
}
```

Can someone help to solve this? Is there any other way to expand the model?

PS: I am relatively new to the HoloLens 2 development platform and trying to learn.

EDIT: I figured out why it was not working. The reason was my object was not at 0 position. So I changed the position of the object and now it is working but when I want it to come back to the original position, some nested child objects are not aligning properly like the original position.

Comment: Where do you invoke the `ToggleExplodedView` method? According to your description, it seems like this method is invoked twice in a row. And it is a pure Unity issue, there is no difference in behavior when deploying on the HoloLens, you can test it in Unity editor.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT I have created a simple button and on that button, I am calling this ToggleExplodedView(). I tried to do everything but it is now working the way I want it to work.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT I am testing this in unity editor

Comment: So it is working for you? Or there is a typo in your comment? If it is not working, since the ToggleExplodedView method will reset the model the second time it is called, recommend you add a breakpoint on this method to check the state of the isInExplodedView property. For more information please refer to this link: [Use breakpoints in the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT.. No it is not working but thanks a lot for the suggestion. I will check that and will get to back here with an update.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT..I checked the value of the property "isInExplodedView" and found out that it is setting the value properly but still when the model explodes, the exploded parts are going behind. I checked the value of one of the child components of my model. Original position (-0.0001916264,-0.002934699,-0.004094132) and after explosion (-0.3354658,-0.2842034,-0.2500371). The only thing I want to do is to explode the model normally and not behind.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out with some help why it was not working properly.

1. Model was not positioned at origin
2. If condition when model is in exploded view and user want to see the original model (Unexploded)

Below is the solution:

1.

```
mesh.explodedPosition = (item.bounds.center - transform.position) * 2f + transform.position;
```

2. if (Vector3.Distance(item.meshRenderer.transform.position, item.originalPosition) < 0f)
   {
   isMoving = false;
   }

This tweeks are working for me.

If there is anything wrong or my code need some improvements (It does), kindly do comment.